# pm-utils hooks not working to un/load modules on suspend on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, alternatives?

Tags: suspend, power-management, 15.10, sd-card, pm-utils

Suspend & hibernate are not working properly as long as I have an SD card inserted into my machine. Removing it is not a sustainable option for my set-up.

The internal SD Card reader of my Macbook (MBPr 10,1) is the culprit, it has some issues with high speed SD cards, a problem I was able to [partially work around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1307674).

In order to get suspend & resume to work I still have to unload & reload the sdhci module manually every time, as pm-utils hooks do not seem to work anymore ([at least not like this](https://superuser.com/questions/620201/how-to-force-ubuntu-debian-mint-to-unload-modules-at-suspend-to-disk), but I also tried sleep.d and several other locations).

Is there another automated and reliable way to unload and reload modules on suspend/resume?

(Also, what about AC/battery energy profiles if pm-utils is deprecated?)